# Can't clear an ArrayController when sortProperties is set

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm looking for a way to clear an `ArrayController`, but get an error when `sortProperties`:

```
App.SwatchesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  clear: function () {
    this.clear(); // Error: Using replace on an arranged ArrayProxy is not allowed. 
  },
  sortProperties: ['occurences']
});
```

If I remove `sortProperties`, it will work just fine. Of course I can clear the controller by doing:

```
this.set('model', []);
```

But it would like to stick to `clear()`, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just `this.clear()` will make the `arrangedContent` change, and this isn't allowed. I think it happens because `arrangedContent` isn't the source of truth, just the `model` property. `arrangedContent` is intented to be some reorganized data based on model property, like: filters, orders, sort etc. So you need to always change the source (`model`), not the arranged data.

So you need to use `this.get('model').clear();` instead of `this.clear();`.

Your code updated will be the following:

```
App.SwatchesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  clear: function () {
    this.get('model').clear();
  },
  sortProperties: ['occurences']
});
```

Comment: This way it works. Should I also chain other method like this, e.g. `this.get('content').addObject({})`?

Comment: I think this is a good idea. Because the error is throwed in `replace` method. And it's called for all methods that change the elements from array. Like: clear, insertAt, removeAt etc.

Comment: Also Ember's author recommends use `model` instead of `content`: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2007#issuecomment-21659090

Comment: `model` is an alias to `content` https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/controller.js#L43. You will have the same effect, but I agree, it's a good pratice to use it. I will update the answer.